# according to following a post i tried to change system partition size ,now my storage is unuseable what should i do?

Tags: adb, internal-storage, partitions

my cmd gone wrong here

[image]

i tried three times but failed(every time same problem)
now os is working in system folder but storage is not showing
is there any solution?

Comment: flash stock ROM and don't try ever again until you know what you are doing!