# How should I partition my android device? Should I use gpt or msdos?

Tags: root-access, internal-storage, recovery-mode, lineageos, partitions

so I got myself into a [really bad situation](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/tif3b7/vayu_formatted_the_system_from_recovery_and_now_i/) and I need to re-partition my device.

I already pushed `parted` and `mkfs` to `/sbin` ([following this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XEjDKGzd-3o)) and made them executable with `chmod 777`, i just need to know how am i supposed to partition my device

is it similar to a normal linux system (`/boot` and `/`, maybe a separate `/home` partition)?

[image]

Comment: I doubt you get answer because no one wants responsible for [mess up](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/245794) partitions or [brick](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/218269)

Comment: I genuinly want to help you but I won't since the success rate is like 50%

Comment: [Android device partitions and filesystems](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/info-android-device-partitions-and-filesystems.3586565/)

Comment: according to the reddit link this question is solved without repartitioning at all